# Monitoring a microservice architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, prometheus

I'm designing an architecture that similar to what's described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/).  The diagram is: 
[image]

My question is how do you monitor such an architecture where independent pieces compose into a logical unit?  It's almost as if we need a monitoring system that checks S3 for .zip files and then polls S3 for the corresponding png files.  If *after* X hours no png files are found then alert.

Is there a tool that does timeseries analysis?  Does Prometheus do this?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Prometheus (usually) works by pulling metrics off a server, so I dont see how you could apply it directly onto S3, unless you generate a dynamic page with the number of png's on S3.

in details:
The way Prometheus works is by pulling metrics, available as HTTP pages, from servers. Your server will need to publish this special page called /metrics and Prometheus will go there and get its contents.

If you can generate a *dynamic* *public* page on S3 that would export the current number of .pngs in your bucket, that this should work. just point Prometheus to it.

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd monitor such systems with Prometheus is by instrumented the applications that talk to S3/SQS.  See this code for an example of how we instrumented an application that talks to S3: https://github.com/weaveworks/cortex/blob/master/chunk/chunk_store.go#L177

We use these histograms (scraped and aggregated by Prometheus) to alert us when PUTs or GETs to S3 and failing, or taking too long.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you'd like to push metrics from Lambda into Prometheus, you should take a look at https://github.com/weaveworks/prom-aggregation-gateway.